# Using AutoML Vision REST API in Android App

Tags: android, google-api, google-oauth, google-cloud-vision, automl

I want to use **AutoML Vision REST API in Android** App.

The recommended way to Authenticate with API is through Service Accounts.

Another option is to use OAuth2.0.

So How can I **use Service Account Authentication in Android App** or OAuth2.0 is the only option?

Also, suggest if there is any other way to achieve this with concise and compact code.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the recommendation is to have your application communicate to a backend server that handles the requests and their authentication to GCP. This will allow to have a better control and security of your Project and you can just follow the recommendations for [setting up authentication for server to server production applications](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production).

If you really want to authenticate as an end user, then for Production scenarios the best option is to use OAuth 2.0, which allows your application to access resources on behalf of a user, setting the proper scopes. Check [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp) to learn more about how to use OAuth 2.0 for Mobile & Desktop Apps.

Alternatively, you could use API keys, but you have to be careful and restrict the API keys to your specific Android Apps and other proper restrictions in order to avoid misuse. Also, you would have to follow [other best practices](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6310037) such as reviewing your code before publicly releasing it in order to ensure that your code does not contain API keys.